# jQuery get ID from div

Tags: jquery

I have an `AJAX` post, where I can delete a specific `ID` with. However, it runs when clicking on a link, `<a href="#">Remove</a>`. However, I need a specific `ID`. Is there a way I can add a value to the link, which I then can pass on to an `AJAX` post?

Example:

```
<a href="#" deletevalue="2">Remove</a>
```

Comment: so you want to remove the value after ajax? and pass a link within the ajax? what do you mean? what link?

Comment: Yes, you can use data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes, and send it to ajax request. But, even custom attributes will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data-*`:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-id="2" >Remove</a>
```

You can read more about `data-*` attributes in the docs **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** or **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put rel attr. You can echo inside the id

```
<a href="#" rel="the_ID_that_you want">Remove</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But consider adding an ID to your link (I mean, in terms of DOM) so you can have use a better jquery selector.

```
$('a').attr('deletevalue', 2);
```

Note quite sure what you want to do with this `deletevalue` then, but you might want to use `$('a').attr('deletevalue')` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a onClick="delete(id)">Remove</a>
```

Then to JQuery

```
function delete(id){...}
```

You can do your stuff in that function. 
There are so many ways to achieve that. That is just one of them